# Wix and Office 365 Name Servers on the same domain

Tags: dns, domain

I would really appreciate help on this as I am not really familiar with domain management.
Our Office365 is using a domain that we bought, and we have added the Office365 Name Servers in our domain management page.
Then we have set up a website with Wix, and so we added Wix name servers to the same domain management page (refer picture in the link below). However, the Wix website keeps on losing connection to the domain, causing the website to be down. I believe this is because we can't have two different places as Name servers for the domain. How do I go around to solve this issue, I am really at a lost here. Thanks in advance.
https://i.stack.imgur.com/u1PCL.png

Answer (score 1):

> I believe this is because we can't have two different places as Name servers for the domain.

Specifically, you cannot have servers which provide *different data* for the same domain. In a setup like this, clients have no way of knowing which server they should ask about which subdomain – they pick one at random and if it says "No such name" then there's no such name as far as the client cares.

If you want both services to use the same base domain, you will need to pick *one* as the DNS host (nameserver) and manually add individual DNS records for the other.

See Wix documentation pages:

- https://support.wix.com/en/article/connecting-a-domain-to-wix-using-the-pointing-method

  List of Wix DNS records you need to add to Office 365 or another DNS provider.
- https://support.wix.com/en/article/connecting-office-365-to-a-domain-in-your-wix-account

  The opposite method – list of Office 365 DNS records you need to add to Wix.
- https://support.wix.com/en/article/pointing-vs-name-servers-domain-connection-methods

  Note the list of features that only work when Wix nameservers are hosting your domain.

  <sub>("the pointing connection method"? Okay that's a new one...)</sub>